# Deadlock with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, deadlock, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that without multiprocessing loops over an array with 3-tuples and does some calculation. This array can be really long (>1million entries) so I thought using several processes could help speed things up.

I start with a list of points (`random_points`) with which I create a permutation of all possible triples (`combList`). This `combList` then is passed to my function.
The basic code I have works but only when the `random_points` list has 18 entries or less.

```
from scipy import stats
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp

def calc3PointsList( points,output ):
  xy = []
  r = []
  for point in points:
    // do stuff with points and append results to xy and r
  output.put( (xy, r) )


output = mp.Queue()

random_points = [ (np.array((stats.uniform(-0.5,1).rvs(),stats.uniform(-0.5,1).rvs()))) for _ in range(18)]
combList = list(itertools.combinations(random_points, 3))
N = 6
processes = [mp.Process(target=calc3PointsList, args=(combList[(i-1)*len(combList)/(N-1):i*len(combList)/(N-1)],output)) for i in range(1,N)]

for p in processes:
  p.start()
for p in processes:
  p.join()
results = [output.get() for p in processes]
```

As soon as the length of the random_points list is longer than 18 the program seems to go into a deadlock. With 18 and lower it just finishes fine. Am I using this whole multiprocessing module the wrong way?

Comment: Do you see the same problem with N = 4 or N = 2?  For your last line, I think it should be `results = [output.get for x in range(output.qsize())]`

Comment: Yes, still hangs with N=2 or N=4 which means 1 or 2 jobs (I create jobs in the range of (1,N) so N is exclusive. If I tried N=3 or N=5 (so there are 2 or 4 jobs) it also hangs if you meant it's connected with the number of jobs.
Thanks for the hint with the result line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the problem is described in the [programming guideline](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods) mentioned by user2667217:

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

Removing the join operation made it work. Also the right way to retrieve processes seems to be:

```
results = [output.get() for p in processes]
```

Answer (score 2):

I do see anything else you posted that is clearly wrong but there is one thing you should definitely do : start new processes in a `if __name__=="main":` block, see [programming guideline](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

```
from scipy import stats
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp

def calc3PointsList( points,output ):
  xy = []
  r = []
  for point in points:
    // do stuff with points and append results to xy and r
  output.put( (xy, r) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = mp.Queue()
    random_points = [ (np.array((stats.uniform(-0.5,1).rvs(),stats.uniform(-0.5,1).rvs()))) for _ in range(18)]
    combList = list(itertools.combinations(random_points, 3))
    N = 6
    processes = [mp.Process(target=calc3PointsList, args=(combList[(i-1)*len(combList)/(N-1):i*len(combList)/(N-1)],output)) for i in range(1,N)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    results = [output.get for x in range(output.qsize())]
```

Comment: I assume you mean `if name=='__main__'`. I added this thanks. But regardless of that, the problem persists.